# How to rename bunch of directories in windows?

Tags: batch-file, rename, batch-rename

I would like to change directory name from

```
view_pictures
personal_pictures
scenic_pictures
```

to

```
2017_view_pictures
2017_personal_pictures
2017_scenic_pictures
```

Each folder has files inside, and this is just a fictional example, in the source dir there are more than 20K sub directories so manual rename is impossible.
I tried getting the list with *tree* command,
So then I can manipulate the list using notepad++ and some regex,
But tree will not give full path so i can generate a command.

This is the directory structure:

```
root path
    picsfromA
        view_pictures
        personal_pictures
    picsfromB
        view_pictures
        personal_pictures
        scenic_pictures
    picsfromC
        personal_pictures
        scenic_pictures
    picsfromD
        personal_pictures
    picsfromN
        scenic_pictures
```

this is the desired directory structure:

```
root path
    picsfromA
        2017_view_pictures
        2017_personal_pictures
    picsfromB
        2017_view_pictures
        2017_personal_pictures
        2017_scenic_pictures
    picsfromC
        2017_personal_pictures
        2017_scenic_pictures
    picsfromD
        2017_personal_pictures
    picsfromN
        2017_scenic_pictures
```

***UPDATE***
I am also trying like this:
the difficult part is to break the path string and reconstruct it.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set folder_path=%%f
for /D /r %%f in (*) do (
    set folder_path=%%f
    echo %folder_path%

    if "%folder_path:~-13%" EQU "view_pictures" (
      REM path without last folder name
      REM construct path without folder name
      REM [ren old folder] , [new folder.]
    )

  )
```

Comment: You should have a look at Bulk Rename Utility - - http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

Comment: Things would be much easier if you have WSL om your Windows 10 (if it is).

Comment: @iBug It's only easier if you don't know batch but bash ;-)

Comment: I really like RegexRenamer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution using FOR /D /R

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%F in (*) do (
  if /i "%%~nxF" == "view_pictures" ren "%%F" "2017_%%~nxF"
  if /i "%%~nxF" == "personal_pictures" ren "%%F" "2017_%%~nxF"
  if /i "%%~nxF" == "scenic_pictures" ren "%%F" "2017_%%~nxF"
)
```

Or simplified with an extra loop

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%F in (*) do for %%A in (view personal scenic) do (
  if /i "%%~nxF" == "%%A_pictures" ren "%%F" "2017_%%~nxF"
)
```

Or you could use the FOR /F solution that LotPings posted.

You could also use my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). JREN is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required.

```
jren "^" "2017_" /s /d /fm "scenic_pictures|personal_pictures|view_pictures"
```

Comment: saved my day, great, elegant solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`for /D /r %%f in (*) do (` is an invalid combination, see the output with an echo.

- You could stack two `for /D` to iterate first the `picsfrom..` and then the subfolders or
- A `for /f`parsing dir output filtered with a regular expression ($ anchors at the end) to match only wished subfolders with a findstr:

---

```
@Echo off
Set "Folders=view_pictures$ personal_pictures$ scenic_pictures$"

For /f "delims=" %%F in (
     'Dir /B/S/AD ^|Findstr /I "%Folders%"'
) Do Ren "%%~fF" "2017_%%~nxF"
```

Sample tree on my ramdrive A:

```
> tree
A:\
└───root path
    ├───picsfromA
    │   ├───2017_personal_pictures
    │   └───2017_view_pictures
    ├───picsfromB
    │   ├───2017_personal_pictures
    │   ├───2017_scenic_pictures
    │   └───2017_view_pictures
    ├───picsfromC
    │   ├───2017_personal_pictures
    │   └───2017_scenic_pictures
    ├───picsfromD
    │   └───2017_personal_pictures
    └───picsfromN
        └───2017_scenic_pictures
```

**EDIT** Output of `for /D /r %%A in (*) do Echo:%%A` on my system

```
A:\root path\picsfromA
A:\root path\picsfromB
A:\root path\picsfromC
A:\root path\picsfromD
A:\root path\picsfromN
A:\root path\picsfromA\2017_personal_pictures:A:\root path\picsfromN
A:\root path\picsfromA\2017_view_pictures:A:\root path\picsfromN
A:\root path\picsfromB\2017_personal_pictures:A:\root path\picsfromN
A:\root path\picsfromB\2017_scenic_pictures:A:\root path\picsfromN
A:\root path\picsfromB\2017_view_pictures:A:\root path\picsfromN
A:\root path\picsfromC\2017_personal_pictures:A:\root path\picsfromN
A:\root path\picsfromC\2017_scenic_pictures:A:\root path\picsfromN
A:\root path\picsfromD\2017_personal_pictures:A:\root path\picsfromN
A:\root path\picsfromN\2017_scenic_pictures:A:\root path\picsfromN
```

Comment: Your FOR /F solution is fine. But there is nothing wrong with `FOR /D /R %%F in (*) DO ...`. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: @dbenham I get two pathes (fullpath and root path) delimited with a colon with that command for sub folders so it maybe valid but has unexpected results.

Comment: I don't understand your description of the FOR /R /D output. On my machine, I get the expected recursive listing of the full path of every child folder under the root. I've successfully used that construct for years.

Comment: @dbenham Appended to my answer the output of the command.

Comment: What the hell is that funky @!**% ??? I can't imagine what is causing that result on your machine. I've certainly never seen anything like it. I'd love to get a better understanding. You might post this issue as a topic on http://www.dostips.com/forum. It is a good site for collaborative back and forth investigations.